# Need sqsh to ignore a dollar sign

Tags: sql-server, sqsh

*The Environment:*
Solaris 10, /bin/sh script using sqsh and freetds to talk to an MS SQL Server

*The (TLDR) Problem:*
I need sqsh to ignore a dollar sign and pass it through to MS SQL.

*The Background:*
I'm writing some code that dynamically builds SQL to alter existing indexes but when it runs, I get errors:

```
Msg 2727, Level 11, State 1
Server 'HOST\SERVER', Line 1
Cannot find index 'foo'.
```

I dig around and see that there is no index named `foo` but there *is* one named `foo$bar`.

The built-up input SQL input looks fine...

```
% grep 'foo' input.sql
alter index [foo$bar] on ...
```

...and running this SQL through a New Query session or a third party app succeeds.  However, the results when passed through sqsh don't see past that dollar sign:

```
% sqsh -e -i input.sql -o output.sql
% grep 'foo' output.sql
1> alter index [foo] on ...
```

...which suggests it's interpreting `$bar` as a variable or something.

Anyone know how to get sqsh to escape a dollar sign or allow one to pass through?  I've tried various combinations of quotes and backslashes.

Help me, stackoverlow.  You're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference manual on page 5 states: *"Note that in order to prevent the expansion of a variable use either single quotes, or two \’s, like thus:*

```
1> \echo \\$name
$name
```

So, I believe that to prevent sqsh to substitute $bar with an empty string, you have to write something like:

```
alter index [foo\\$bar] on ...
alter index ['foo$bar'] on ...
```

To test it you can try first with SELECT `'foo\\$bar' = 1` or something similar.

Comment: This is exactly the document reference and solution I was attempting to find.  A quick rewrite and the SQL runs as expected.  Thank you muchly.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to disable buffer expansion altogether by executing:

```
\set expand=0
```

on the sqsh prompt, or specify this command in the .sqshrc file, or start sqsh with the parameter

```
sqsh -e -i input.sql -o output.sql -Lexpand=0
```

If expansion is on (default) then sqsh will substitute the variable $bar with its contents.